# .Net Core 3.1 Worker Service with Entity Framework Core SqlServer error on SaveChanges()

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-core

**Program.cs**

```
public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }
        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args)
        {
            var host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseWindowsService()
                .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
                {
                    var connection = hostContext.Configuration.GetConnectionString("D365BCIntegration");
                    var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<D365BCIntegrationContext>();
                    optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connection);//,
                    services.AddScoped<D365BCIntegrationContext>(s => new D365BCIntegrationContext(optionsBuilder.Options));
                    services.AddHostedService<PullItemWorker>();
                });
            return host;
        }
    }
```

**DbContext.cs**

```
public partial class D365BCIntegrationContext : DbContext
    {
        
        public D365BCIntegrationContext(DbContextOptions<D365BCIntegrationContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        public virtual DbSet<TmpItem> TmpItem { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<TmpItem>(entity =>
            {
                entity.ToTable("TmpItem");
                entity.Property(e => e.id).UseIdentityColumn();
                entity.Property(e => e.No)
                    .HasColumnName("No.")
                    .HasMaxLength(20);

                entity.Property(e => e.Description)
                    .IsRequired()
                    .HasColumnName("Description")
                    .HasMaxLength(100);

                entity.Property(e => e.Description2)
                    .HasColumnName("Description2")
                    .HasMaxLength(50);
            });
            OnModelCreatingPartial(modelBuilder);
        }

        partial void OnModelCreatingPartial(ModelBuilder modelBuilder);
    }
```

**TmpItem Model**

```
public partial class TmpItem
    {
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        [Key]
        public long id { get; set; }
        public string No { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Description2 { get; set; }
    }
```

**In Worker**

```
 public PullItemWorker(ILogger<PullItemWorker> logger, IServiceScopeFactory serviceScopeFactory)
 {
   _logger = logger;
   _serviceScopeFactory = serviceScopeFactory;
 }

** in ExecuteAsync**
var context = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<D365BCIntegrationContext>()
 TmpItem _modelItem = new TmpItem();
 _modelItem.No = _item.No;
 _modelItem.Description = _item.Description;
 _modelItem.Description2 = _item.Description;
 context.TmpItem.Add(_modelItem);
 context.SaveChanges();
```

Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.Execute(IRelationalConnection connection)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.Execute(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalDatabase.SaveChanges(IList`1 entries)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChanges(IList`1 entriesToSave) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChanges(DbContext _, Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChanges(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChanges(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChanges()

Comment: It looks like you are missing the first line of the actual error mesage, your question only contaains the stack trace.

Comment: I printed StackTrace from Exception